# Need to write a find/replace script for items in a text file

Tags: excel, text, batch-file, replace

I'm faced with a problem.  I have a text list of thousands of cities and their gps coordinates.  The format is:

```
City,longitude,latitude,Parent
```

so an example might be:

```
Los Angeles,34.11N,118.41W,California
```

The problem is that I need the long/lat to be in + and - values so the correct entry would be:

```
Los Angeles,34.11,-118.41,California
```

So the script would be something like

- Find "W" or "S" (west and south get the "-" symbol)
- if you find either of those letters within the 2nd or 3rd "," insert a "-" symbol before the first number. (we don't want to affect the words in the 1st or 4th field)
- then delete any letter from the long/lat field.

This could be done a zillion ways - excel, .bat file, something else?

If anyone could help with this I'd be very grateful. 
Thanks

Comment: just import the data into excel since the data seems to be CSV, then just apply some  excel magic to the correct column...

Comment: When it comes to "excel magic"... im a muggle.  The magic would need to find the letter and then insert a symbol at the beginning.  Do you know the formula for that?

Answer (score 1):

Try this Batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist thefile.tmp del thefile.tmp
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in (thefile.txt) do (
    set longitude=%%b
    set sign=!longitude:~-1!
    set longitude=!longitude:~0,-1!
    if /I !sign! == S set longitude=-!longitude!
    set latitude=%%c
    set sign=!latitude:~-1!
    set latitude=!latitude:~0,-1!
    if /I !sign! == W set latitude=-!latitude!
    echo %%a,!longitude!,!latitude!,%%d>> thefile.tmp
)
del thefile.txt
ren thefile.tmp thefile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The following formula should get you started:

Using the following as input (Note that you need to convert the "." to "," in excel"):

```
A2          B2      C2      D2
Los Angeles 34.11N  118,41W California
```

This is from my swedish version of excel

```
=OM(HITTA("W";C2);-1*(BYT.UT(C2;"W";""));)
```

I think this translates to:

```
=IF(FIND("W";C2);-1*(REPLACE(C2;"W";""));)
```

The outcome of this is that cell C2 is converted to `-118,41`.

**Update**

Excel/open office is great for many things but I always found the text-handling
to be extremely awkward... You seem to be open for alternative solutions and
my suggestion is that you install python. It looks like you are on windows;
here there are two ways to get python:

1. install python from [python.org](http://www.python.org/)
2. install cygwin from [cygwin.com](http://www.cygwin.com/) and with that python

alternative 2. has the advantage that you will get a compete unix/linux
environment on windows!

This is how a (bit verbose) python solution might look; even though perhaps
you never seen python before you should be able to understand the code quite
easily...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

def convert(word):

    if 'W' in word or 'S' in word:
        word = word.replace('W', "")
        word = word.replace('S', "")
        word = '-' + word
    return word

with open("input") as fd:
    for line in fd:
        line=line.strip()
        line = line.split(',')
        line[1] = convert(line[1])
        line[2] = convert(line[2])
        print ",".join(line)
```

Comment: Hmmm,  I seem to be getting 511 errors.  I should point out im using open office and not excel.  I'll see if i can find excel...

Comment: Yes that code looks good - I can see what it intends to to.  Please dont laugh - but I can't exactly "open a file" in python right?  I imagine theres a line of code to specify the text document?  If you had a file located in say

user/myusername/downloads

and python was located in 

/usr/local/bin/pythonw

what might the exact lines for terminal be?
right now im on a mac.  i could be on a pc, potentially.
thx

Comment: change the shebang to `#!/usr/local/bin/pythonw` and use `with open("/user/myusername/downloads/file.txt") as fd:` then make the file executable using `chmod u+x name_of_script` and execute it using `./name_of_script`